# Security in IOS9 Document Directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, ios9

I'm developing an app to store images(Like a Folder Locker) **securely**. Currenlty images stored in its own **document directory**. Since **iOS9** provide more security to app's documents directory, do i need to worry about encrypting images when store ? or is it anyway secure if i just save images in the app's document directory?

App can olny access with a password.

Please advice with confidence thanks.

Currently I store like this:

```
NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyPics"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
[data writeToFile:imagepath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: What security do you want? What are your concerns?

Comment: if i want to protect the image which stores is secure enough? @rmaddy

Comment: Protect the image from what? You are not being clear. What are you trying to prevent? Are you trying to prevent the device user from seeing the images? Are you trying to prevent the device user from deleting or changing the images? What? Be specific.

Comment: My app is like a Folder Locker if i save the image in app's directory , can another party access the images without login to my app ?@rmaddy

Comment: Anyone that has access to the device can easily access the images without using your app at all. This is true no matter which folder you use unless you encrypt the files.

Comment: What how? app's directory can't access from another sources according to iOS 9 right? @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

you can also add key in file.plist

```
Application supports iTunes file sharing  to NO
```

by default it is NO

Comment: Thanks i will do that too .@vaibby

Comment: What does this have to do with security?

Answer (score 0):

Phones running iOS9 and having a passcode get default file protection that encrypts application data. Here is a quote from Apple's doc

> Protected Until First User Authentication
>   (NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication): This class behaves in the same way as Complete Protection, except that the decrypted class key is not removed from memory when the device is locked. The protection in this class has similar properties to desktop full-volume encryption,   and protects data from attacks that involve a reboot. This is the default class for   all third-party app data not otherwise assigned to a Data Protection class.

Although, it seems that default value has been changed to `NSFileProtectionComplete`. I just ran a test on iOS 9.3.4 creating a file in the documents directory and it automatically gets `NSFileProtectionKey` attribute set to `NSFileProtectionComplete`. Which means that the file gets encrypted when the phone is locked.

The snippet used to create a file:

```
NSURL *theTestFileURL  = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
theTestFileURL = [theTestFileURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"testFile.txt"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:theTestFileURL.path]) {
    [[@"test content" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] writeToFile:theTestFileURL.path atomically:YES];
}
```

Attributes of the created file:

```
{
    NSFileCreationDate = "2016-09-05 20:46:28 +0000";
    NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 501;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = mobile;
    NSFileModificationDate = "2016-09-05 20:46:28 +0000";
    NSFileOwnerAccountID = 501;
    NSFileOwnerAccountName = mobile;
    NSFilePosixPermissions = 493;
    NSFileProtectionKey = NSFileProtectionComplete;
    NSFileReferenceCount = 2;
    NSFileSize = 68;
    NSFileSystemFileNumber = 1113757;
    NSFileSystemNumber = 16777218;
    NSFileType = NSFileTypeDirectory;
}
```

To summarize, by default on iOS 9 your app's data get encrypted when device is locked.